# Routing error in running mailer application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/mymmailer/index"

Althought there exists such a file in the specified path
app/views/mymmailer/index.rhtml

Comment: But there's no correct route in `routes.rb`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define this in your routes.rb

resources :mymmailer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ok...not a problem...Can you please let us know the correct answer?